# Make JSON payload fields case insensitive when mapping to Java Object in REST API developed using SpringBoot

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, spring-boot

I am working on REST API developed using SpringBoot application. Here I want to make the fields in the payload(JSON) as case insensitive when mapping to a Java Object. Below is my code.

**Payload**

```
{"limit":1,"name":"MATTHEW PHILLIPS"}
```

**Request Object**

```
private String limit;
private String name;

public String getLimit() {
      return limit;
    }

    public void setLimit(String limit) {
        this.limit = limit;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
```

I map the JSON payload to java Object directly using `@RequestBody` Spring annotation. My question here is How do I make the java Object to map to the fields ignoring the case.

Regards,
Rakesh

Comment: i want to do it in spring mvc. Any idea ?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Well, if its Spring Boot application you can have this in your `application.properties` file:
`spring.jackson.mapper.accept_case_insensitive_properties=true`

or if you use yaml:

```
spring:
  jackson:
    mapper:
      accept_case_insensitive_properties: true
```

Comment: i want to do it in spring mvc . Any idea?

Comment: @parladneupane this might be helpful:
http://www.baeldung.com/properties-with-spring

Comment: I needed to use hyphens:   
`spring.jackson.mapper.accept-case-insensitive-properties=true`

Comment: For anyone using in `application.properties`, use this instead  `spring.jackson.mapper.accept-case-insensitive-properties=true`

Comment: in `.yml` it also works with hyphens:
`spring.jackson.mapper.accept-case-insensitive-properties: true`

Answer (score 3):

I recently found a solution via Annotation config:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.MapperFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

@Configuration
public class Config {

    @Bean
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.configure(MapperFeature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES, true);
        return mapper;
    }

}
```

I'm using these dependencies:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.3.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-module-jaxb-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.5</version>
    </dependency>
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

For me the most simple solution was using com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat annotation in the class definition of my requestBody (i'm using 2.5.0 spring-boot, but it is a fasterxml annotation so it is probably not related):

```
@JsonFormat(with = {JsonFormat.Feature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES})
```