# How to make jsonData case insensitive and in Spring MVC

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc

New to spring ,

i am trying to access json object in `@RequestBody MYPOJO pojo` which works fine , but my json data needed to be same as variable name in pojo and case sensitive. best i did find from web is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30924816/make-json-payload-fields-case-insensitive-when-mapping-to-java-object-in-rest-ap) , but not synchronize with my project , i am using spring mvc. So how can i make case insensitive my json with pojo?

the way i receive json

```
@RequestMapping(value = "create", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void createPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp, @Valid @RequestBody Post post,
        Errors errors) throws CustomException, IOException {
```

json data

```
function jsonForPost(isEdit, id) {
var post = {};
if (isEdit) {
    post.id = id;
}
post.name = $("#name").val();
return JSON.stringify(post);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

## With `Spring Boot`

```
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.MapperFeature;

@Configuration
class Configs {
    @Bean
    public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer initJackson() {
        Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer c = new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer() {
            @Override
            public void customize(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder) {
                builder.featuresToEnable(MapperFeature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES);
            }
        };

        return c;
    }
}
```

## Without `Spring Boot`

```
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder;
import org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.MapperFeature;

    @Configuration
    @EnableWebMvc
    public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {  
        @Override
        public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
            Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder = new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder();
            builder.indentOutput(true);
            builder.featuresToEnable(MapperFeature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES);
            converters.add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(builder.build()));
        }   
    }
```

I have a POJO with a variable name in it:

```
public class Pox {

    String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }


}
```

and a Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/create", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void createPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp, @Valid @RequestBody Pox post,
        Errors errors) {
    System.out.println(post.getName());


}
```

I have tested with **Postman** with:

name, Name, NAme, nAme.

All of them worked.

Comment: can you give me imports for Config file

Comment: how can i linked up with Config file file ? i am not in spring boot.

Answer (score 0):

With springboot using the `application.yml` file =>

```
spring:
  jackson:
    mapper:
      accept-case-insensitive-properties: true
```